# Pause a Videojs on Slick carousel

Tags: javascript, video.js, slick.js

2I need some help, I'm using several videojs html players on slick slider sycing carousel. My problem is when I click on other carousel thumbnail to go to the other video the first video keeps playing. I'd like to pause any video on click any thumbnail.

My html is:

```
<div class="slider-for">
        <div class="video-wrap">
            <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
  poster="images/video/cover-video2.png"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="images/video/Kalima2.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="images/video/Kalima2.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
        </div>
        <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="example_video_2" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
  poster="images/video/cover-video1.jpg"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="images/video/Kalima1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="images/video/Kalima1.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
        </div>
        <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="example_video_3" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
  poster="images/video/cover-video-students.jpg"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="images/video/Students.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="images/video/Students.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
        </div>
        <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="example_video_4" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
  poster="images/video/cover-video3.jpg"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="images/video/Kalima3.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="images/video/Kalima3.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
        </div>
        <div class="video-wrap">
            <video id="example_video_5" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
  poster="images/video/cover-video-students2.jpg"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="images/video/Students2.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="images/video/Students2.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
        </div>

        </div>
            <div class="video-thumb">
                <div><div id="thumb"><img src="images/video/video2.png"></div></div>
                <div><div id="thumb"><img src="images/video/video1.png"></div></div>
                <div><div id="thumb"><img src="images/video/video3.png"></div></div>
                <div><div id="thumb"><img src="images/video/video4.png"></div></div>
                <div><div id="thumb"><img src="images/video/video5.png"></div></div>

            </div>
```

I find this js:

```
 _V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){

  var player = this;

  var pausebutton = document.getElementById("thumb");

  pausebutton.onclick = function(event) {
    player.pause();
  };

});
```

With this function I can pause only the first video, I'd like some help for a function when I click on single thumbnail I could pause any playing video and it should to work for all thumbnails too. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you are having is that you have several video tags with the same ID: "example_video_1".

I suggest giving each video tag their own ID. Then you'll be able to access them individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes perfect sense, but I forgot to say as I already try to change the ID.  <br/> The problem in this case is that one single thumbnail should pause any video on playing, it don't should be linked to pause an specific video, and I have no idea how can I do it.  <br/>Make more sense seeing how it works:  <br/> [basic links](http://tonybezerra.com/galeria/surf/index.html)  <br/>  <br/>On Kalima TV when you play some video and click some thumbnail to go to next, the first video keeps playing audio when it hide.